# Как правильно произносится слово "датер"?

Tags: фонетика

Как правильно произнести слово: *дАтер* или *датЁр*?

Answer (score 1):

Словарями пока не фиксируется. Но, исходя из того, что слово английское, полагаю: дАтер.